# View is not added when using addView()

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am making a window to open an empty `dialog` and write comments.

The dialog initially has an empty item where i can write one comment.

Comments can be up to one line.

Pressing the `Enter key` dynamically creates an item that allows you to write the next comment.

I was wondering whether to use `RecyclerView` or `addView()` for this function.

Since this dialog was also opened from the `recycler view item of the parent`, it would be complicated when using `RecyclerView` again, so I used `addView()`.

I don't know if this is the right choice.

This is because data management seems to be difficult because the created comment must be saved in the `parent's recycler view item`.

Anyway, using `addView()` does not add the view.

There is no such thing as an error, but it cannot be added.

What is the cause?

***writeing_comment_item***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment.WritingCommentDialogFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start_point"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" * "
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/comment_edit" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment_edit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="22"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/start_point"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***fragment_writing_comment_dialog***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment.WritingCommentDialogFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/start_point"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" * "
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="22" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***WritingCommentDialogFragment.java***

```
public class WritingCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    LinearLayout mContainer;
    EditText editText;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_writing_comment_dialog, container, false);
        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.comment_edit);
        mContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.container);

        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override // IME actionNone (Enter Key)
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                View inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.writing_comment_item, mContainer, false);
                mContainer.addView(inflater1);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setDialogSize();
    }


    private void setDialogSize() {
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you added a **horizontal** **LinearLayout** and after you added an **EditText** with `android: layout_width = "match_parent"` that's why your Comment is added on your container view but is not visible because of the **EditText**.

if I understood correctly you must change
`android: orientation = "horizontal"` by `android: orientation = "vertical"` in your **fragment_writing_comment_dialog**
so that the commentary will be displayed above the **EditText**

And also you need to change the orientation on your Container LinearLayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment.WritingCommentDialogFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/start_point"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" * "
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="22" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```